# SQL Random Tables

Tags: sql, graph

I want to implement graph coloring using databases.

There is a table that will store all the vertices (1,2,3...) and a table that stores the name of all colors(red,blue,green,etc..).

Now a want to create a coloring table with columns vertex and color which will take all possible combinations from the above tables and then check the constraints in each of those tables. Whichever table satisfies the constraints of graph coloring is a solution.

Now how to create tables for each combinations??

Guys please help. Stuck on it from a while...

An example instance:

vertex
1
2
3

Colors
red 
blue

coloring
a)
1 red
2 blue
3 red
b)
1 red
2 red
3 blue
c)
1 blue
2 red
3 red
.
.
.
6 tables

Comment: Are you trying to generate all possible graphs from your set of vertices and then find all valid coloring solutions for each graph?

Comment: not finding all possible graphs. I have an edge table that can define the graph. I'll be using that table to check whether the coloring is correct. I just have to see all possible colorings and find the correct one from it.

Comment: Could you give an example of the result set you'd like? I can't understand exactly what you'd like to do

Comment: I have given an example in the problem description above...the 6 coloring tables are the ones i want to obtain...with vertex and colors given in separate tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand. Am I getting this correctly: You want to create a number of different tables? How are these tables different? What columns will the tables have? For one example table, could you give all the rows?

Comment: let the vertex table be: 1 2 3 4

let the color table be:R B G

coloring table: 1) 1 R 2 B 3 G 4R

Comment: 2) 1 R 2 B 3 G 4 B
3) 1 R 2 B 3 G 4 G
4) 1 R 2 B 4 G 3 R

Comment: 5) 1 R 2 B 4 G 3 B
6) 1 R 2 B 4 G 3 G
7) 1 R 3 B 4 G 2 R

Comment: 8) 1 R 3 B 4 G 2 B
9) 1 R 3 B 4 G 2 G

Comment: 10) 2 R 3 B 4 G 1 R
11) 2 R 3 B 4 G 1 B
12) 2 R 3 B 4 G 1 G

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Vertices.vertex, Colors.Color from Vertices
CROSS JOIN Color from Colors
```

EDIT: Seeing the new comments: This doesn't sound like a problem that is well suited for SQL, mainly because your number of columns in your resultset is dependent on the number of rows in your vertices table. That's not something that is easy in SQL (you probably need a multistep process, using dynamic sql through sp_execute). Since the ordering of the colums carries significance, you can't return a resultset containing only each vertex - color pair either, because the order in which the rows are returned may vary. To me it sounds like a problem better handled outside the database engine. You can still use the above cross join to get a preliminary dataset, where you filter out some conditions you have on the set.

Comment: thnx but I dont just want the cross product...i want the resultant table to have 1 entry for each vertex. And al such tables shud be formed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, so I'll make some assumptions. Assuming you have a table called Vertex, with the following rows:

```
1
2
3
```

... and a table called Color, with the following rows:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

... you can generate a table of all possible combinations with a simple unconstrained join, like this:

SELECT *
INTO VertexColor 
FROM Vertex, Color

The result will be a new table, with the following rows:

```
1, Red
1, Green
1, Blue
2, Red
2, Green
2, Blue
3, Red
3, Green
3, Blue
```

Happy to help further if this does not answer your question.

Comment: Thnx for the help....but in the resultant table there should be only 1 entry for each vertex. And in such a way all possible tables should be constructed..